# Javascript widget not working inside a Sharepoint web part

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

i've got a javascript widget that loads contents from a 3d party website and i need to use it in a sharepoint web part. The problem is that the widget works everywhere (wordpress, other websites etc.) but not inside a sharepoint web part.

Pasted in a web part it only shows chars like $0 after saving, the strange thing is that if i paste a different widget like the twitter one to retrive last tweets it works.

Is there anybody who could have a look at the code and tell me if there is something wrong with it? I'm a newbie with sharepoint, i had to clear the website name and url because the project is not yet bublic... thanks!

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='xxx/stylesheets/widget.css'/>

<div id='xxx'></div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
var require = document.createElement('script');
require.src= 'xxx/javascripts/require-jquery.js';
(document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(require);
var xxx = document.createElement('script');
xxx.src= 'xxx/plugins/4f357c414918c20001000003.js';
require.onload = function () {
  $r = jQuery.noConflict();
  (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(xxx);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

"[Insert JavaScript into a Content Editor Web Part (CEWP)](http://www.tcscblog.com/2012/01/17/insert-javascript-into-a-content-editor-web-part-cewp/)" should help you.

Comment: Thank you Ravi! Now the widget displays fine in a content editor web part, the only problem is that every click inside the widget buttons causes the main page to refresh, any idea?

Comment: Can u use return false in button onclick method?

Comment: It worked with the return false thank you Ravi now the widget works like a charm! : )

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to include all webpart elements on which a webpart depends on as an embedded resource or in you _layouts folder. This will ensure any images, xml, icons and scripts are running in a proper location. Here I am assuming require-jquery.js is not deployed with your webpart via SharePoint solution (wsp). Also you should register your client side script in webpart's PreRender method or use following example for inline code,

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="skl" Name="ProjectName/Scripts/require-jquery.js" runat="server" OnDemand="false" Localizable="false" />
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Sal! You are right no js is deployed on Sharepoint also because i will use the widget in other websites, and i'd like to have all the files centralized, they are all hosted on mine 3d party website that provides the widget. Strange thing is that other javascript widgets like the Twitter one are working like a charme in the web part but mine not... I'm not expert with Sharepointanyway i will try your solution if there is no other way.